# Verificar checkbox desmarcado php

Tags: php, checkbox

Eu tenho vários checkbox dinamicos que são listados da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach($configs as $config): ?>

<?php echo utf8_encode($config['description'])?><input style="margin-left:10px;" type="checkbox" name="in_active[<?php echo $config['config']?>]" <?php if($config['in_active'] == true){echo 'checked';}?>/> <?php if(isset($config['value'])){echo "<input type='number' class='form-control' name='value[".$config['config']."]' step='0.01' min='0' value='".$config['value']."'>";}?> <br>

<?php endforeach?>
```

Esses dados são enviados para um controller, onde tenho um array chamado "in_active", o qual recebe os checkbox.

```
$data = array();

        if(isset($_POST)){
            
            $data['in_active'] = $_POST['in_active'];
            $data['value'] = $_POST['value'];

            $updateConfig = new Configuration();
            $updateConfig->updateAllConfigs($data);

        }
```

Esses dados são enviados para um model, onde faço um foreach para dar um update no db.

```
            $in_active = $data['in_active'];
            foreach($in_active as $config => $val):
                    if($val){
                        $val = true;
                    }else{
                        $val = false;
                    }
                    $sql = $this->db->prepare("update configurations
                    set
                        in_active       = :in_active
                    where config = :config
                    ");
                    
                    $sql->bindValue(':config',$config);
                    $sql->bindValue(':in_active',$val);
                    
                    $sql->execute();

            endforeach;
```

Mas dessa forma só consigo atualizar, quando estão desmarcados, quando desmarco não, eu sei que isso se dá por conta que os checkbox só enviam algo quando estão marcados. Então, como posso contornar isso? Como posso fazer para atualizar o db, quando desmarcar o chexbox?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive a seguinte ideia, já que consigo atualizar quem está marcado, vou mudar tudo para 0 no db, depois atualizo os que foram marcados